# Evaluate improper integral using the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin(ax)}{x}dx
$$ 
using the cauchy-Goursat theorem.

I'm trying to understand this example given in my complex analysis lecture notes.

First, the initial problem is converted to an integral on the complex plane:
$$
I = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{sin(ax)}{x}dx = \lim_{\delta\to 0} \int_{\delta}^{\infty}\frac{e^{iax}-e^{-iax}}{2ix}
 = \lim_{\delta\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}\setminus[-\delta,\delta]}\frac{e^{iaz}}{2iz}dz
$$

Then, using this closed curve $\Gamma$ ([Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB0Xo.png)) and applying the Cauchy-Goursat theorem, we have:

$$
\oint_{\Gamma}\frac{e^{iaz}}{2iz}dz = \int_{\left(-R,R\right)\setminus\left[-\delta,\delta\right]}\frac{e^{iaz}}{2iz}dz  + \int_{\pi}^{0}\frac{e^{ia\delta e^{i\theta}}}{2} d\theta + \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{iaRe^{i\theta}}}{2}d\theta = 0
$$

And the desired integral is just the first integral on the right side of this equation when $R\rightarrow \infty$ and $\delta \rightarrow 0$

The text just assumes that the limit can be taken inside the integralso we have

$$
\lim_{\delta\to 0}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{e^{ia\delta e^{i\theta}}}{2} d\theta = \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\pi}d\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}
$$

The other integral should vanish after the limit is taken

$$
\lim_{R\to\infty} \left[ \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{iaR e^{i\theta}} d\theta \right] = 0 
$$

but I can't really see why this happens. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would save yourself some trouble if you'd first u-subbed $ax=t$. In fact, you will then see that the value of $a$ doesn't do a whole lot...If would make the subsequent computation easier in the sense that parameter $a$ is gone.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't think it would change that much here since the constant i not really affecting the calculations.

Comment: That's also true, it is more a general observation that the value of $a$ does not influence the outcome of the integral, which is remarkable in a way